# Jogar data que retornou do ajax em foreach php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, foreach

Tenho um search ajax que retona alguns dados com base no que foi pesquisado, como faço para jogar esse 'data' que vem de um ajax em um foreach no php
?

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: 'get',
    url: '{{route('
    videos.index ')}}',
    data: {
        search: $valor
    },
    // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "text",
    beforeSend: function() {

        $("#resultado").html("Carregando...");
        // document.getElementById('paginate').style.display = 'none';
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if ($.trim(data)) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#resultado').append(data);
            $('#last_videos').html(" ");
            document.getElementById('create_video').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('paginate_total').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('paginate_ajax').style.display = 'block';

        } else {
            $('#resultado').html("Video não encontrado no banco de dados ou URL invalida");
            $('#last_videos').html(" ");
            // document.getElementById('create_wistia').style.display = 'block';
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#last_videos').html(" ");
        $('#resultado').html("Erro ao pesquisar...");
    }
});
```

Quero pegar o resultado do success ajax e jogar nesse foreach

```
<div id ="last_videos">
    @foreach($data as $video)
    <div class="sc-box " id="{{ $video->id }}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
                <span class="sc-code"><big>{{ $video->code_video }}</big></span>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cinza"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></a>
                (<span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span> {{ $video->duration }})
                <a href="{{ route('videos.edit', $video->id) }}" class="fa fa-edit"></a><br />
                <b>{{ $video->title }}</b> 
                <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="{{ route('videos.edit', $video->id) }}">
            @if ($video->image)
            <img style='width: 200px; height: 250px' src="{{ URL::to('/uploads/' . $video->image) }}"  class="sc-class-gallery img-responsive">
            @elseif ($video->thumbnail)
            <img style='width: 200px; height: 250px' src="{{ $video->thumbnail }}"  class="sc-class-gallery img-responsive">
            @endif
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @else
    <img src="{{ URL::asset('images/no-video.png') }}" width="250">
    <h3>{{ trans('field.video_index') }}</h3>
    <p>{!! trans('field.text_video_index') !!}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Poste seu código, ajuda na solução do problema.

Comment: _"em um foreach no php"_ - queres dizer no JavaScript ou PHP?

Comment: Coloquei o código para melhor exemplificar.

Comment: Ajax é javascript, então a resposta do request terá que ser tratada com javascript e não com PHP. Podes eventualmente enviar a resposta em uma nova requisição em que tens no server-side PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você vai precisar inflar esses dados em html para depois jogar na sua pagina, um dos jeitos, seguindo o seu modelo é criando um template em string:

```
var templateVideos = `<div class="sc-box " id="%%id%%">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
            <span class="sc-code"><big>%%code_video%%</big></span>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cinza"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></a>
            (<span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>%%duration%%)
            <a href="%%routeEditVideoId%%" class="fa fa-edit"></a><br />
            <b>%%title%%</b> 
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="%%routeEditVideoId%%">

        <img style='width: 200px; height: 250px' src="%%thumbnail_url%%"  class="sc-class-gallery img-responsive">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>`;
function inflate(data) {
  var inflado = templateVideos;
  inflado = inflado.replace(/%%id%%/g, data.id);
  inflado = inflado.replace(/%%title%%/g, data.title);
  // e vai substituindo tudo utilizando regExp na sua logica
  return inflado;
}
```

E então usar no seu callback de sucesso

```
success: function(data) {
    var content = parseData(data);
    if (data.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          var videoIteracao = inflate(data[i])
          $("last_videos").append(videoIteracao);
        }
        console.log(data);
        $('#resultado').append(data);
        $('#last_videos').html(" ");
        document.getElementById('create_video').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('paginate_total').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('paginate_ajax').style.display = 'block';

    } else {
        $('#resultado').html("Video não encontrado no banco de dados ou URL invalida");
        $('#last_videos').html(" ");
        // document.getElementById('create_wistia').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta pegar esse retorno do JS e dar um json_decode, ai você transforma para objeto do php e consegue manipular no seu foreach.